# How to check all checkboxes? Trying to check all check boxes, test passes, but visually I do not see that they been checked

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
@Test
public void checkAllFilters() throws InterruptedException {
    couponSearchPage.navigateToAvailableCoupons();
    couponSearchPage.refineBarClick();
    driver.findElement(By.name("group1")).isDisplayed();
    WebElement checkBoxList = driver.findElement(By.name("group1"));
    System.out.println("Is checkbox displayed? " + checkBoxList.isDisplayed());

    List<WebElement> checkBoxFiltersList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='c -checkbox']//following:: input[@type='checkbox']"));
    for(WebElement checkBox : checkBoxFiltersList){
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        checkBox.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        //mainPage.ajaxClick(checkBox);
    }
    // Assert if any checkbox left checked
    List<WebElement> allCheckboxList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='c-checkbox']//following:: input[@type='checkbox']"));
    if(!allCheckboxList.isEmpty()){
        Assert.fail();
    }

}
```

**Trying to check all check boxes on the page, but it doesn't check, even though test passes. Xpth is incorrect or I need ajaxClcick?**

```
<div class="c-checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" id="Baby &amp; ChildCare" class="c-settings-form__filter-checkbox c-checkbox__input js-update-filter" name="filter-Baby &amp; ChildCare" value="Baby &amp; ChildCare">
     <label for="Baby &amp; ChildCare" class="c-checkbox__label"><span></span>Baby &amp; ChildCare</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post a link to the page you are automating?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot. I just need to figure out how to create the right xPath I guess with HTML code above.

Comment: The 'right XPath' for the HTML code above is `//div[@class='c-checkbox']/input`. But I'm assuming that's not working, which is why you are here -- hence, the need to see full page HTML or link. It's impossible to know why your current choice of XPath is not working correctly without the larger context of what the entire page looks like.

Comment: https://stopandshop.com/coupons-weekly-circular/digital-coupons/#/available

Comment: Basically, I have to click on each Refine -> Filter option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on `label` element not on `input`.

```
List<WebElement> checkBoxFiltersList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='c-checkbox']//label"));
```

Also with locator you use to get checked checkboxes is wrong, use:

- xpath: `//div[@class='c-checkbox']//input[@checked='true']`
- css: `.c-checkbox input[checked='true']`

Also change Assert to proper check if all checkboxes are selected:

```
Assert.assertEquals(driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".c-checkbox input[checked='true']")).size(), 
            checkBoxFiltersList.size());
```

---

**Update**, code with different assertions as example:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".c-sort-filter")).click();

List<WebElement> checkboxes = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector(".c-checkbox label")));
List<String> labels = checkboxes.stream().map(WebElement::getText).collect(Collectors.toList());

for (String label: labels) {
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(String.format("label[for='%s']", label))).click();
    // wait until loading disappear
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".c-spinner")));

    // check if input is selected
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeSelected(By.cssSelector(String.format("input[id='%s']", label))));
}

// check if input is selected by compare tags with checkboxes
List<String> selectedFilters = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".divider-view-filters-list .c-xbubble")).stream().map(WebElement::getText).collect(Collectors.toList());
Assert.assertEquals(selectedFilters, labels);
```

Comment: If I use this xPath, it clicks on the first one, and after it fails.

Comment: `org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`. I used ajax click method, the same - it clicks on the first option and after fails.

Comment: Because you have to wait until JavaScripts will completed. For that you can use `WebDriverWait`. Let me test

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed xPath and added Assert -Test passes, but I do not see that check boxes are checked.

Comment: Check answer update. You can use assertion you want, or split it in different test cases